# c++ how can I call B and A Methodes?

Tags: c++

I want to print (see below) without adding any other variables or objects... how can I do that? thanks a lot... B: : p r i n t A: : druck A: : p r i n t

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    void print() { cout << "A: : p r i n t " << endl; }
    void druck() { cout << "A: : druck " << endl; }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    void print() { cout << "B: : p r i n t " << endl; }
    void druck() { cout << "B: : druck " << endl; }
};
int main() {
    A * a = new B();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my solution was to make the print methode of B static and then call it in the main without object, but I want to do that without changing the code... :(

Comment: Have you tried `a->print()`? What happened?

Comment: It prints only the methodes of A :)

Comment: if you want it to use methods of B class you need to make the methods virtual in A

Comment: Yes, but then can I use also the methode of A? I want to use bothe of them... I want to print :
B: : p r i n t
A: : druck 
A: : p r i n t

Comment: You can make your methods like this: void print() { cout << "B: : p r i n t " << endl; A::print(); } it will do what you need

Comment: Thank you Andrey, but the problem ist that I have do that withoud changing those methodes... I can do my changes only in the main function and also without adding any variables or new object :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call `B`s through a `static_cast`, something like:

```
a->print();
static_cast<B*>(a)->print();
```

Comment: Thank you so much :-D that is what I need